# jumbled character set

Tags: awk, character-encoding

*In my Linux env, for some unknown! reason when I process a raw unformatted file which I copied from* Win7prof (was encoded in utf-16),  *the resulting file is all jumbled.   It will print OK in Linux using* cat *command,
but if I* **vi***,  its also jumbled like this:*

> Username;Full Name;Groupsï¼å¾çæçæ¸ææ´æã¬äçæ°æ°âä¸ææ´æã¬ççæçççà¨æâ¸ææ´æ¤çâ¸çæçæççæçäæ¼çâ¸çæçæççæçäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´ã¬ääåå¼ççæççà¨æâ¸ææ´æ¤çâ¸çæçæççæçäæ¼çæææçäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´ã¬æ¨æ¤çæâ´ççæççà¨ã¬^@æææ´æ¤çâ¸æææ¤æäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´ã¬äææ´æ¤çææ´æ¤çâ¸æææ¤æäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´ã¬æ¨æ¤çæâ´ççæççà¨ã¬^@ææçæ¼æ¸â¸ææ°æçææ æçäæ¼çæææçææ æçäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´à¨ã¬^@ææçæ¼æ¸â¸ææ°æçææ æçäæ¼çæææ°æâ¸ææ¼æ´ã¬æ¨æ¤çæâ´ççæ¼æ´ã¬ä¸äå¼ççæççà¨ã¬^@ææçæ¼æ¸â¸æ

*the same file when moved to Windows,  opens up with first few words in* **English***, then the rest of the file prints in Chinese characters! 
looks like:*

> Username;Full Name;Groups＊嗾猀攀爀渀愀洀攀㬀䘀甀氀氀 一愀洀攀㬀猀琀愀琀甀猀਀愀⸀愀洀椀琀⸀猀愀爀愀猀眀愀琀䀀漀爀愀挀氀攀⸀挀漀洀㬀䄀 匀愀爀愀猀眀愀琀愀⸀愀洀椀琀⸀猀愀爀愀猀眀愀琀䀀漀爀愀挀氀攀⸀挀漀洀㬀䔀䄀匀开甀猀攀爀猀਀愀⸀愀洀椀琀⸀猀愀爀

*When I check the char-set of the file, it returns:* 


**application/octet-stream**


and I can't run **iconv** command because it rejects **octet-stream** 

as a character set!

The only sure thing I know is that file formats between my linux and Windows have been compatible all along, I've modified files on linux, ftp back to windows for ever without any issues until now with this command:

> [me@localhost fkhodada]# awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '

> { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1,$2,$i }
>   ' file1 > final

Comment: Windows does *really* weird things with encodings. But do make sure the output of `locale(1)` on the linux box is correct.

Comment: Please let us know: ------ **1.** How was the file created? (application, possibly procedure) ------ **2.** How was the file transferred to Linux? Could not there be any conversion (like the implicit one in FTP)? ------ **3.** Please post a hex dump of the file: `hd file` or `xxd -g1 file` or `od -tx1c file`. ------ **4.** What you wrote: "_the same file when moved to Windows, opens up with first few words in English, then the rest of the file prints in Chinese characters!_" strongly suggests that the file content is corrupted. Why do not you consider this possibility?

Comment: Addition to **4.** ...or opening in a correct application is fine? ------ **5.** If yes, what is the correct application and what is the application which shows the Chinese characters?

Comment: You my friend asked all the right questions, and that lead me to solve the mystery.  I started fresh with a small txt file, just to go through and replicate all the steps I was about to report back to you.  In that process I realized that the problem lies in default settings of notepad in windows.  I'll explain in more detail tomorrow when I'm fresh.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this scenario I realized the encoding problem was in the original file I exported from my windows env.
So I did repeated the same routine, this time, at "save as" argument, chose encoding type to UTF8 and the file looked fine in Linux, and after modified and exported back to windows, looked fine in Windows notepad too.